# How to bring up the Windows 8 on-screen keyboard in a desktop app

Tags: directx, touch, windows-8, multi-touch

I have a fullscreen DirectX desktop app, and would like to display the on-screen keyboard when the user taps a textbox in my game. Is there a way to do this while in fullscreen mode?

Comment: Is there any way to hide the keyboard?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Executing osk.exe will pop up the more old-fashioned on-screen keyboard.
The Windows 8 touch keyboard will pop up by executing

```
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe
```

I just figured that out, since I'm working on a fullscreen desktop app that is running on a tablet PC without keyboard attached.

Severin.

Comment: Was looking for a better way of doing it, but this seems to be the only reasonable method that actually works.

Comment: And how do you hide it?

Answer (score 3):

Same answer as Severin Stampler but in order to find the correct path from c# I use:

```
var path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonProgramFiles) + @"\Microsoft Shared\ink\TabTip.exe";

if (!File.Exists(path))
{
   // older windows versions
   path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.System) + @"\osk.exe";
}
```

Comment: When you're running a 32bit application, TabTip.exe won't be found on a 64bit system. GetFolderPath will give you the "Program Files (x86)" folder, the tabTip.exe in there is called "TabTip32.exe"

Answer (score 1):

If it is a desktop app, you might need to invoke `ShellExecute` for `osk.exe`.

If it is a Metro application, then you cannot invoke the SIP from the app itself. As per the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465404.aspx):

> This means that applications cannot programmatically invoke the touch
>   keyboard via manipulation of focus. Big culprits here in the past have
>   been webpages—many of them set focus by default in

Answer (score 1):

You can show the Windows 8 touch keyboard quite easily:

http://brianlagunas.com/showing-windows-8-touch-keyboard-wpf/