# How to request standard on screen keyboard on devices like Microsoft Surface?

Tags: wpf, windows, winapi

We're developing a cross-platform application that renders all its UI via OpenGL. I.e. there is no "real" controls in terms of Windows frameworks.

What we need is to pop-up Microsoft Surface keyboard each time user input is required and there is no physical keyboard connected.

The only approach I [found](http://brianlagunas.com/showing-windows-8-touch-keyboard-wpf/) requires admin privileges which is inappropriate.

Is there any standard call in WinAPI, .NET or whatever SDK that has C++ interface?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to bring up the Windows 8 on-screen keyboard in a desktop app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11874029/how-to-bring-up-the-windows-8-on-screen-keyboard-in-a-desktop-app)